# Sync PouchDb with CouchBase through Sync Gateway by channel - error 404 for local document

Tags: couchbase, pouchdb, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am trying to sync pouchDB with CouchBase through Sync Gateway by channel. 
In pouch I have :

```
var da = new PouchDB('example_DE');
    da.sync(remoteDB, {
        create_target: true,
        live: true,
        retry: true,
        filter: "sync_gateway/bychannel",
        query_params: {
            channels: ["DE"]
        }
    })
```

Sync config file:

```
{
"log": ["*"],
"CORS": {
    "Origin":["http://127.0.0.1:8887","http://localhost:8887"],
    "LoginOrigin":["http://127.0.0.1:8887","http://localhost:8887"],
    "Headers":["Content-Type","Authorization"],
    "MaxAge": 1728000
},
"adminInterface": "127.0.0.1:4985",
"interface": "0.0.0.0:4984",
"databases": {
    "db": {
        "bucket":"db",
        "username": "Administrator",
        "password": "123456",
        "server": "http://localhost:8091",
        "sync":
            `function (doc) {
               channel(doc.channels);
            }
            `,
        "users": {
            "GUEST": {"disabled": false, "admin_channels": ["*"] }
        }
    }       
}
```

I can find in browser in IndexedDB my documents but in console I get this error:
GET http://localhost:4984/db/_local/nKlC5IrimnHOiQZcwE_LYA%3D%3D? 404 (Not Found)

Comment: What versions of Pouch, Sync Gateway, and Couchbase Server are you using?

Comment: PouchDB - 6.4.3, Sync Gateway - 1.5, Couhbase Server - Community Edition 5.0.1

Comment: I suspect two issues here.  First, if I understand PouchDB options correctly, you're asking for a server-side filter based on a design document.  Have you set up a design doc in Sync Gateway?  That could account for the 404 error.  Second, there are compatibility issues with filtered replications.  I don't know whether this would affect your case or not.  You can read about the problem here: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-ios/issues/1139

Comment: What do you mean set up a design doc? I can see document in Sync Gateway in admin interface

Comment: Reviewing it further, I think I'm wrong.  It looks like you're using the wrong endpoint to retrieve the document.  If it has been synced from PouchDB,
 it should be http://localhost:4984/db/doc_id.  See https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.5/references/sync-gateway/rest-api/index.html#/document/get__db___doc_  _local is for special purpose docs.  By design, they aren't replicated.
 (Just for reference on design docs, see: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.4/guides/sync-gateway/views/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Request to endpoint with ..../_local generates PouchDB. I use only  da.sync(...) in my code. If I use sync function without filter: "sync_gateway/bychannel" I don't have any error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to do it without having the need to remove "sync_gateway/bychannel":

```
var local = new PouchDB("yep");
var remote = new PouchDB("http://user:password@localhost:4984/bucket/");

// sync starts here
local.replicate.from(remote, {
    filter: "sync_gateway/bychannel",
    query_params: {
        channels: ["DE"]
    }
});
```